# Right Approach to Make cart in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making a shopping cart in asp.net with c# using DataTable stored in Session and all items stored in DataTable.

```
public DataTable dtCart = new DataTable();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["dtCart"] == null) { CreateCartTable(); }

    }
}
protected void CreateCartTable()
{
    dtCart.Rows.Clear();
    dtCart.Columns.Clear();

    dtCart.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Prd_Id", Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dtCart.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Prd_Name", Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dtCart.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Prd_Img", Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dtCart.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Qty", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
    dtCart.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Rate", Type.GetType("System.Decimal")));
    dtCart.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount", Type.GetType("System.Decimal")));
    dtCart.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TotalAmount", Type.GetType("System.Decimal")));

    Session["dtCart"] = dtCart;

}
```

Is this right approach or any other way is more elegant and light on application?
FYI I'm using web forms.

Comment: You can ask such questions on http://programmers.stackexchange.com that site would let you ask for best algorithms!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a class to cart:

```
public class Cart
{
     public string Prd_Id{set;get;}
     public string Prd_Name{set;get;}
     //and so on...         
}
```

then in page:

```
Cart obj=new Cart{Prd_Id="1",Prd_Name="John"};
Session["dtCart"]=obj;
```